# SQL query that is a mix of a LEFT join and an INNER join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables :

```
TableA        TableB
id            id
amt           amt
idUser        idTableA
```

Let's say the following data is in TableA :

```
1   10  1
2   20  1
3   30  1
4   40  2
5   50  3
6   60  4
7   70  4
```

and the following data is in TableB :

```
1   10  1
2   20  2
3   21  2
4   51  5
5   70  7
```

All fields are not nullable.

if I want to know what items in TableA have no 'link' to tableB (through the TableB.idTableA field), I can do this query :

```
SELECT a.id, a.amt
FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN TableB b on b.idTableA = a.id
WHERE b.idTableA IS NULL
```

and it will return the following :

```
3   30
4   40
6   60
```

if I want to know what items in TableA (that do have a link to tableB) for which the amt values are not identical in each table I can do :

```
SELECT a.id, a.amt, b.amt
FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b on b.idTableA = a.id
WHERE a.amt <> b.amt
```

and it will return :

```
2   20  21
5   50  51
```

Now, I would like a query that does the following :
Return the idUsers for which *only some* of their entries in TableA have a link with TableB (meaning that for the idUser, there must also be some entries in the TableA with no link between the two tables) and for which at least one entry has different amounts between the two tables among the lines that are linked.

In my example, the idUser 1 would be returned by such a query because the third entry in TableA fulfills the first condition (some entries with no link) and there exists an entry for which amounts are different (linked with the value 2 for idTableA are amounts 20 in TableA vs 21 in TableB)

userId 2 will not be returned because it has no line linked between the two tables,

userId 3 will not be returned because it does not have a line in TableA without link in TableB

userId 4 will not be returned because although it has 1 line in TableA without link and also 1 line with a link, the line with a link has its amounts identical between the 2 tables.

So really it is a mix of the two initial queries...

Thanks for your input and my apologies for the basic formatting and language, I hope this is clear enough :)

Comment: I think your query ending in `WHEREb.idTableA IS NULL` should also return TableA ids 4 and 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with loners as (
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a 
LEFT JOIN TableB b on b.idTableA = a.id
WHERE b.idTableA IS NULL
), 
diffs as (
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a 
INNER JOIN TableB b on b.idTableA = a.id
WHERE a.amt <> b.amt
)
select loners.userID
FROM loners
INNER JOIN diffs on LONERS.userID = DIFFS.userID
```

Comment: +1 that was easier than I thought...is there any better (performance-wise) implementation or is that the best way to do it?

Comment: performance depends on a whole lot.  for one, are you looking for speed, least memory usage, least cpu usage, least io usage?  What are you optimizing for?  Also, it depends on what your underlying schemas are, what indexes you used, what harware they reside on, what the weather is in timbuctu, etc.

Comment: but that is the same as using subqueries right? I've always thought that avoiding subqueries whenever possible is good and that the same result can be achieved with a better performing query without subqueries?

Comment: subqueries are not the devil, but they are dangerous.  In this case, it shouldn't be particularly expensive.  The really bad ones are where the subquery is in the SELECT clause, meaning it is run once per result row, but even those are ok at times.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.idUser
FROM
(SELECT a2.id, a2.amt, a2.idUser 
    FROM TableA AS a2 
    LEFT JOIN TableB AS b2 
    ON b2.idTableA = a2.id 
    WHERE b2.idTableA IS NULL
) AS a 
INNER JOIN TableB AS b
ON b.idTableA = a.id
WHERE a.amt <> b.amt;
```

I'm not sure if this is actually any more efficient, but here is how I would have done it.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution :)